# SQLServer Writing union in a single statement

Tags: sql-server, union

I have query as given below:

```
SELECT * FROM [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN] 
WHERE proj_id = 167592 
AND taskrsrc_id NOT IN
(
SELECT taskrsrc_id FROM [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST]
WHERE proj_id = 167592 
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN] 
WHERE proj_id = 167592 
AND fin_dates_id NOT IN
(
SELECT fin_dates_id FROM [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST]
WHERE proj_id = 167592 
)
```

Basically the query returns all the rows where either taskrsrc_id or fin_dates_id should not present in the subquery data.

Can I do this without using UNION??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

```
select  * 
from    [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN] t1
where   proj_id = 167592 
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST] t2
        where   t2.proj_id = t1.proj_id
                and (
                    t1.taskrsrc_id = t2.taskrsrc_id
                    or
                    t1.fin_dates_id = t2.fin_dates_id
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN] 
WHERE proj_id = 167592 
and not exists (select null from [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST]
                 WHERE proj_id = TRSRCFIN.proj_id 
                   and (TRSRCFIN_TEST.taskrsrc_id = TRSRCFIN.taskrsrc_id
                    or TRSRCFIN_TEST.fin_dates_id = TRSRCFIN.fin_dates_id)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN] 
WHERE 
    proj_id =167592 
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL
        FROM 
            [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST]
        WHERE 
            [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST].proj_id = [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN].proj_id
            AND 
            (
                [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST].taskrsrc_id= [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN].taskrsrc_id
                OR  [PMDB_ARC].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN_TEST].fin_dates_id= [PMDB_DEV].[dbo].[TRSRCFIN].fin_dates_id
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

why?

if you have proper indexes (one on proj_id+taskrsrc_id and one on proj_id+fin_dates_id) it is most likely that this UNION query will use **both indexes and be faster** than a query that does not use the UNION (and can't use both indexes).  I'd worry more about optimizing the `*` and the `NOT IN` if anything.